# left position math formula

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I try to write down the following equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{flalign*}
\left \| \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2 \right \| = \\ 
\sqrt{( r_{1,x}-r_{2,x} )^2 + ( r_{1,y} - r_{2,y} )^2 } = \\ 
\sqrt{( (x\cos(\Omega y)-y\sin(\Omega y))+\rho\cos(\Omega y) )^2 + ( x\sin(\Omega y)+y\cos(\Omega y) + \rho\sin(\Omega y) )^2 }
\end{flalign*}
\end{equation}
```

I am using the following math packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

But instead to be write on the left side it's continuing to stay in the right side.
How can I write it in a better way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the `fleqn` option of `article` what you want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, `flalign*` starts math mode, so can not be nested inside `equation`.

Then, if you want the stuff inside `flalign*` to be left aligned, you have to put a `&` at the beginning of each line and a `&&` at its end, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
&\left \| \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2 \right \| = &&\\
&\sqrt{( r_{1,x}-r_{2,x} )^2 + ( r_{1,y} - r_{2,y} )^2 } = &&\\
&\sqrt{( x\cos(\Omega y)-y\sin(\Omega y)+\rho\cos(\Omega y) )^2 + ( x\sin(\Omega y)+y\cos(\Omega y) + \rho\sin(\Omega y) )^2 }&&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The result is not really good, anyway. BTW, there was an unneeded right parenthesis after `y\sin(\Omega y)` and one before `x\cos(\Omega y)`.

IMHO, you can also further eliminate parenthesis so to avoid bad boxes warnings, and move the equal sign down in the next line, in this way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
&\left \| \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2 \right \| &&\\
&\quad=\sqrt{( r_{1,x}-r_{2,x} )^2 + ( r_{1,y} - r_{2,y} )^2 } &&\\
&\quad=\sqrt{( x\cos\Omega y-y\sin\Omega y+\rho\cos\Omega y )^2 + ( x\sin\Omega y+y\cos\Omega y + \rho\sin\Omega y )^2 }&&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a better looking square root you can insert a `\vphantom{r_1^2}` in the latter `\sqrt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
&\left \| \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2 \right \| &&\\
&\quad=\sqrt{( r_{1,x}-r_{2,x} )^2 + ( r_{1,y} - r_{2,y} )^2 } &&\\
&\quad=\sqrt{\vphantom{r_1^2}( x\cos\Omega y-y\sin\Omega y+\rho\cos\Omega y )^2 + ( x\sin\Omega y+y\cos\Omega y + \rho\sin\Omega y )^2 }&&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe a `\quad` to start the third row?

Comment: @egreg Right, no bad boxes.

Comment: Another option might be using `multlined` environment inside the last square root.

Comment: Since the `mathtools` package loads the `amsmath` package, it's not necessary to load the latter package explicitly. To normalize the size of the two long square root symbols, you could encase the former in a `\smash{...}`, or at least a `\smash[b]{...}`, instruction.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, just copied the code and didn't notice that both package were loaded. In regards of `\smash`ing the former, I prefer the result with a `\vphantom`.

Comment: I like your solution, which employs a `\vphantom` in the second square root, too. :-)

Comment: @Manuel I don't like that solution, but you can make an answer with that.

Answer (score 3):

Or this

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
%\begin{equation}
\begin{align*}
\left \| \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2 \right \| 
&=  \sqrt{( r_{1,x}-r_{2,x} )^2 + ( r_{1,y} - r_{2,y} )^2 } \\
&=
\sqrt{( (x\cos(\Omega y)-y\sin(\Omega y))+\rho\cos(\Omega y) )^2 + ( x\sin(\Omega y)+y\cos(\Omega y) + \rho\sin(\Omega y) )^2 }
\end{align*}
%\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The bad box is over `52pt`...

Comment: @karlkoeller -- Mmmm, leaned sth from your post. Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick note, the bad box is removed if the left margin is reduced. This example uses the default setting of LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
\begin{align*}
&\left \| \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2 \right \| = \\ 
&\sqrt{( r_{1,x}-r_{2,x} )^2 + ( r_{1,y} - r_{2,y} )^2 } = \\ 
&\sqrt{( (x\cos(\Omega y)-y\sin(\Omega y))+\rho\cos(\Omega y) )^2 + ( x\sin(\Omega y)+y\cos(\Omega y) + \rho\sin(\Omega y) )^2 } 
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option. Taking karlkoeller's code.
I use `multlined` environment inside the second square root (`\qquad` is just to move it to the right, you can substitute it with whatever you want, even delete it, since `multline` already adds some space).

```
\begin{align*}
    \left\| \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2 \right\| &= \sqrt{(r_{1,x} - r_{2,x})^2 + (r_{1,y} - r_{2,y})^2 } \\
    &= \sqrt{\begin{multlined}
        (x\cos\Omega y - y\sin\Omega y + \rho\cos\Omega y)^2 \\
        \qquad + (x\sin\Omega y + y\cos\Omega y + \rho\sin\Omega y)^2
    \end{multlined}}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

### EDIT

Still another two options.

```
\begin{align*}
    \left\| \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2 \right\| &= \sqrt{(r_{1,x} - r_{2,x})^2 + (r_{1,y} - r_{2,y})^2 } \\
    \MoveEqLeft = \sqrt{\vphantom{r_1^2} (x\cos\Omega y - y\sin\Omega y + \rho\cos\Omega y)^2 + (x\sin\Omega y + y\cos\Omega y + \rho\sin\Omega y)^2}
\end{align*}

\begin{multline*}
    \left\| \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2 \right\| = \sqrt{(r_{1,x} - r_{2,x})^2 + (r_{1,y} - r_{2,y})^2 } \\
    = \sqrt{\vphantom{r_1^2} (x\cos\Omega y - y\sin\Omega y + \rho\cos\Omega y)^2 + (x\sin\Omega y + y\cos\Omega y + \rho\sin\Omega y)^2}
\end{multline*}
```

Both of them look similar to this:

[image]